# Is there a better way to underline the first word in a CStatic control?

Tags: c++, mfc, underline

I have a 2D character array `lineData` and an array of `bool`s, `linesToUnderline`. `lineData` stores just text. `linesToUnderline` stores a true or a false for each line in `lineData`. Each line in `lineData` is being put in a static control (which is created dynamically) in a certain fashion to display to the user.

Now if `linesToUnderline[i]` = true (for 0 <= i < `numLines`), I need to display the line with only the **first word underlined** and the rest of the text normally.

What I'm talking about looks like:

[image: First word underlined]

So currently, what I'm thinking of doing:

1. If `linesToUnderline[i]` = false, go to step 4.
2. Get the first word from `lineData`, put it in a static control, set that control's font to underlined.
3. Remove the first word from `lineData`.
4. Increment starting X position by `lineData`'s pixel length.
5. Put `lineData` in a static control starting at a position X, Y.
6. If `i` < `numLines` go to step 1.
7. Stop.

What do you think of my method? I feel that there must be a better way to do this. If there is, could someone help me out?

Comment: You could draw the underline yourself in the OnPaint method. That looks easier to me, but your method should work also.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed method will not work. The control uses only one font at a time (for all its text) and it does not provide a way to append text at X,Y.

You must subclass the control and paint the text yourself in WM_PAINT. Your paint code can provide the necessary features.

Comment: I think he wanted to add a second static control for the non underlined part.

Comment: As @Michael said, I intended to add two controls. But, this method sounds easier. Any examples you could point me to?

Answer (score 0):

This [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34/Hyperlink-control) implements a hyperlink control by subclassing a static control. You can use it as a base for doing custom underlining. All you have to do is simplify the code.